# transform submited form into Form Data object

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

```
const my_form = document.getElementById('menu_filter')

my_form .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   const formData = new FormData()
   pass_submited_form(formData)
}
```

Lets suppose we have this: how can I populate the `formData` object directly from the form without having to use the `append()` method for every single field?

Comment: Do you want an object which you could use to fill an empty similar form?

Comment: No, let suppose i submitted a form with an input named "my_input" with value 1. I want to create an object of the FormData class that would be the same as when we did .append('my_input',1) in an empty FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the form itself to the FormData constructor.

```js
let form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  
  console.log(formData.get('username'));
  console.log(formData.get('useracc'));

});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: Note that form elements must have an attribute **name** set, otherwise *FormData* ignores them when you pass the form instance to it's constructor.